# Unable to iterate to next ListNode, since the current node is getting overridden with the listnode.next value

Tags: c#, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

This is a [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/) problem.

I saw the solution however while trying to use my own logic, I cannot iterate over to the next node.

```
public ListNode AddTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2)
{
    try
    {
        string l1NodeData = null;
        string l2NodeData = null;

        do
        {
            l1NodeData = l1NodeData + l1.val;
            l1 = l1.next;
        } while (l1 != null);

        do
        {
            l2NodeData = l2NodeData + l2.val;
            l2 = l2.next;
        } while (l2 != null);

        int sum = Convert.ToInt32(l1NodeData) + Convert.ToInt32(l2NodeData);

        var sumInChar = sum.ToString().ToArray();

        ListNode dummyhead = new ListNode(0);
        ListNode ans = dummyhead;

        for (int i = sumInChar.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            ans.val = Convert.ToInt32(sumInChar[i].ToString());
            ListNode tempListNode = new ListNode(Convert.ToInt32(sumInChar[i - 1].ToString()));
            ans.next = tempListNode;
            ans = ans.next;

            //here(ans = ans.next) after assigning the next node, the data of the current node is getting overridden.
        }

        return ans;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

In the above solution where I am assigning `ans = ans.next`, there the current node is overridden with the next node, however, I just want to move to the next node in order to iterate.

Could someone please help me on this?

Comment: You should return dummyHead

Comment: @Chetan , Thank you! It worked but I have not made any assignment to dummyhead right, then how does data reside in that variable?

Comment: You have referenced `ans` to the same node as `dummyHead`, and you *did* assign to `ans.next`, which the first time is synonymous to `dummyHead.next`.

Comment: I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the above solution where I am assigning `ans = ans.next`, there the current node is overridden with the next node, however, I just want to move to the next node in order to iterate.

The assignment is to a *variable*. That never mutates your linked list. This way of assigning to a variable is exactly what you need to traverse a linked list. It does not modify it. In order to mutate it, you will always need to assign to a *member* (property) of a node, like its `next` property.

In the code comments you wrote:

> the data of the current node is getting overridden.

No, it looks like that because you return the reference to the *last* node that was created in the loop. Instead you should `return dummyHead.next;`  This way you return the *first* node that was created in the loop.

In comments you wrote:

> ...I have not made any assignment to `dummyhead` right, then how does data reside in that variable?

You have referenced `ans` to the same node as `dummyHead`, and you did assign to `ans.next`, which in the first iteration of the loop is synonymous to `dummyHead.next`. With those assignments to `ans.next` the nodes get linked to eachother.

Note that `dummyHead` is an extra node that is created to ease the code in the loop -- not having to make a special case for creating the real head node. After the loop that `dummyHead` is then ignored (it served its purpose), and the real head (that is sitting right *after* it) is returned.